# Why am I unable to run a basic CUDA program even though I have nvcc installed in my system?

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, cuda

Why am I unable to run a basic CUDA program even though I have nvcc installed in my system?

```
my_username@192:~$ nvidia-smi
Sun Dec  3 10:23:33 2023
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.223.02   Driver Version: 470.223.02   CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:03:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
| 33%   28C    P8    N/A /  N/A |     14MiB /  3020MiB |     N/A      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:84:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
| 33%   29C    P8    N/A /  N/A |      6MiB /  3022MiB |     N/A      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
my_username@192:~$ nvcc
nvcc fatal   : No input files specified; use option --help for more information
my_username@192:~$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Oct_11_21:27:02_PDT_2021
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.4, V11.4.152
Build cuda_11.4.r11.4/compiler.30521435_0
my_username@192:~$ nano test_cuda_installation.sh
my_username@192:~$ ./test_cuda_installation.sh
0 + 0 = 0
1 + 1 = 0
2 + 2 = 0
3 + 3 = 0
4 + 4 = 0
5 + 5 = 0
6 + 6 = 0
7 + 7 = 0
8 + 8 = 0
9 + 9 = 0
my_username@192:~$
```

```
my_username@192:~$ cat test_cuda_installation.sh
#!/bin/bash

# Create a CUDA source file
cat > test.cu << EOF

#include <stdio.h>

// CUDA Kernel function to add the elements of two arrays on the GPU
__global__ void add(int *a, int *b, int *c) {
    int index = threadIdx.x;
    c[index] = a[index] + b[index];
}

#define N 10  // Size of the vectors

int main(void) {
    int a[N], b[N], c[N];
    int *dev_a, *dev_b, *dev_c;

    // allocate the memory on the GPU
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, N * sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_b, N * sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, N * sizeof(int));

    // fill the arrays 'a' and 'b' on the CPU
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        a[i] = i;
        b[i] = i;
    }

    // copy the arrays 'a' and 'b' to the GPU
    cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_b, b, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    add<<<1, N>>>(dev_a, dev_b, dev_c);

    // copy the array 'c' back from the GPU to the CPU
    cudaMemcpy(c, dev_c, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // display the results
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a[i], b[i], c[i]);
    }

    // free the memory allocated on the GPU
    cudaFree(dev_a);
    cudaFree(dev_b);
    cudaFree(dev_c);

    return 0;
}

EOF

# Compile the CUDA source file
nvcc test.cu -o test

# Run the compiled executable
./test
my_username@192:~$
```

Comment: Look at https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/even-easier-introduction-cuda/ for working examples of code very similar to yours (about third one down using threads).